# Mentioning cell where Pandas Dataframe gets inserted in Google Sheet

Tags: pandas, google-sheets, pygsheets

I have a data frame of 100 rows that I am trying to split into multiple Dataframes as per the below code:

```
for m in df['month'].unique():
    temp = 'df_{}'.format(m) 
    vars()[temp] = finance_metrics[df['month']==m]
```

This gives me 5 new Dataframes as below:

```
df_January
df_February
df_March
df_April
df_May
```

I am trying to have each of these 5 Dataframe inserted into a Google sheet which works well as per the code below. The issue I am having is I am trying to have each of these Dataframes inserted one below the other in the Google Sheet and I am having trouble trying to have the cell referenced accordingly. The below code inserted each Dataframe starting cell A4 and it so happens that the last Dataframe that is created in a loop using the above code overwrites all of the previously created Dataframe. I would like to avoid the Dataframes getting overwritten.

```
wks.set_dataframe(vars()[temp], 'A'+'4+len(vars()[temp])')
```

Comment: Could you also include at least example content of your dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You can pass cell address as a tuple too.

```
offset = 0
for m in df['month'].unique():
  temp = finance_metrics[df['month']==m]
  wks.set_dataframe(temp, (4+offset, 1))
  offset += len(temp)
```